# How do I get both a line and area styled in my d3 line chart?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, line, linechart

I'm using d3 v4.  I'm creating a line chart in which the area is filled with a gradient.  However, I'd like the line that contains the actual data points to have a distinct style.  I have added this in my CSS

```
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: cyan;
    stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
```

and then in my JS

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);
```

but I'm confused about how to have a line and an area.  I think my area is overriding my line style because I can't see the line style at all -- https://jsfiddle.net/rgw12x8d/5/ .

How do I get both the line and area style to appear in my graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using

```
 svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);
```

You actually override the `class` and `d` attributes of the `path` element you just created. First you put there the values of your line, and then you put there the values of the area.

You can duplicate this code to append both of them:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);
```

Here is the fix in your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rgw12x8d/6/